# find source image and it's copyright

Tags: copyright

I want to use some image in my web project if they are allowing for me to use them.(copyright low).
now how can i understand in which site they used before and are they have copyright and register low?
Is exist any way or site to search for this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general image licensing and web design and not photography.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution, but [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com) is a good tool for finding what other places use a certain image, even if it's a different size. Could be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Google Image search has Reverse Image lookup feature.

It works like this:

Step 1. Visit Google Image Search: https://www.google.com/imghp

Step 2. Hover on the right end of search box, you will see a camera sign, click it. Make sure you are using a latest modern browser like Chrome/Firefox.

[image: Hover on the right end of search box]

Step 3. Now it will show a pop up that lets you browse and upload an image or enter an URL.

[image: Enter a direct link or upload the photo]

This will show you wherever on net this image exists. You might be able to track down the source of image this way.

Now as for the Copyright info, if you found the source, you will find that info. I don't know any specific way of finding copyright info.